# Identity Session Start

Tags: .net, session, cookies, asp.net-identity

In MVC 5 project i m using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. I want authorize to user with cookie and session. I record sessions  on redis.

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
      <add name="MySessionStateStore" 
           type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
        host="192.168.13.197"
        port = "6379" 
        accessKey = "" 
        ssl = "false"
        throwOnError = "true"
        retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" 
        databaseId = "0" 
        applicationName = "IddaaWebSite"
        connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" 
        operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1000"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

New Session object must create when user login.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.EmailConfirmed == false)
                return View("_ActivationCodeManuel", user);

            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

            var uSo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            Session.Add(user.Id, uSo);

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "E-posta adresinizi ya da şifrenizi hatalı girdiniz.");

    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

And if session expried on redis, it should link to login page or if user start a new session on another computer the current should expried.
But now it is working with only cookie.

```
    [Authorize]        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();         
        return View();
    }
```

I think i need to ovveride Authorize method. it should check cookie and session on redis ?

Answer (score 1):

Identity framework does not rely on session to store any authentication data, so you'll have to implement that yourself.

I think the best place for cookie invalidation tied to Redis session would be `OnValidateIdentity` event . It is available in `Startup.Auth.cs` and looks like this (default template):

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // other stuff
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });    
        // other stuff
```

You can implement your own version of `SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity` to check for session state.

I've messed about with this event for other purposes, [here is the sample of my code](https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation/blob/master/ClaimsAuth/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L45-L85) - just a sample of how you can implement your own logic there.